# Audio Video Blog

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[<kbd>StackExchange Blogs</kbd>](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)

I think Audio-Video should get a blog, there are so many topics to blog about!

- How to be successful on YouTube
- Pro Tips
- How to podcasts

I think you get the point. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with the audio side than video, but I run across things like that all the time already. I don't think we'd add much value by hosting one of our own (other than to say that it's ours).

This is just my own experience though.

Comment: Yes but StackExchange offers it and I think that it could get some good use

Answer (score 0):

Now that the site has been re-branded to video, this can be something you consider doing again as a community. For us to set it up, you'll just need to show us that:

- You've got at least 3 - 5 writers that will blog on a rather consistent schedule. It doesn't have to be iron-clad, but we've got to make sure we don't launch a dead blog.
- You've got ideas on what kinds of things you're going to write about

When that looks good, we can definitely have a look. There's some [more info](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) in the community blog guidelines post, but that's pretty much the gist of it.